# How to find a value instead of using IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a static table that includes the amount of money and the assigned letter for each amount.

The user should write the amount of money he has and the output should be according.

I have added the example below - I can use IF function if a value =< ; but it will be a big function

[image]

Comment: Can you add a new column to the table that has the bottom value for that letter assignment - i.e. 0, 101, 201 and so on? If so, then it's a simple `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Index/Aggregate:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$6)/($A$2:$A$6>=E2),1))
```

[image]

Comment: It is working !! - But , i'm facing an issue when i'm moving the user input and output cell (E2 & F2) to a different sheet. When i'm adding the name of the sheet to the formela it breaks --> =INDEX('newsheet'!B:'newsheet'!B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('newsheet'!$B$2:'newsheet'!$B$6)/('newsheet'!$A$2:'newsheet'!$A$6>=E2),1))      What am i mising >

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Microsoft365 option:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=@FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6>=D2,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

use Index,Match:

```
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(C2,A2:A6,0))
```

or use this for other sheet:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B2:B6,MATCH(C2,Sheet1!A2:A6,0))
```

[image]